# Where to put random code on rails without auto-loading and require it in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

have a folder with proprietary classes(ex: propcode) with some classes in it(ex: propclass.rb), where should I put that folder and how to require inside controllers?
The classes does not have modules and I can't change them because would brake another applications.

Thank you, I'm new to ruby and have been trying and failing for almost an hour now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to put files like this would be `lib/propcode`. 
If you are only going to use the code in your controller, then you should require it at the top of `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` with the following code:

```
# Require propcode files
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('lib/propcode/**/*.rb')).each do |f|
  require f
end
```

Then you will be able to use these classes in your controller, and they won't be loaded for Rake tasks or background jobs.

Comment: After that I don't need to require it on the controller, just use the class?

Comment: Liked it! In this case it will be auto loaded each time rails stack is loaded! isn't it? But isn't it better requiring it where it is needed?

Comment: @IvanMonteiro - Yep, you won't need to require it on the controller. You can just use the class anywhere in your Rails app.